# Microsoft Windows CVEs?

Tags: windows, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities, windows-10, cve

I know sites like cvedetails and exploit-db feature Windows 10 specific CVEs. But doesnt microsoft.com have a list (or feed) of vulnerability advisories and recently disclosed CVEs? I checked their website (which is a bit confusing to navigate) and [ultimately](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/) lead to [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc?rtc=1), which isnt very helpful. Also tried a few google dorks, but didn't turn up anything. Or an archive of "patch tuesday" advisories? Surely something like this exists...

Comment: How is that not helpful? It shows you an archive of patch Tuesday releases...

Answer (score 2):

This is available in Microsoft's [Security Advisories and Bulletins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/) from [MSRC](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msrc/):

> In this library you will find the following security documents that have been released by the Microsoft Security Response Center (MSRC). The MSRC investigates all reports of security vulnerabilities affecting Microsoft products and services, and releases these documents as part of the ongoing effort to help you manage security risks and help keep your systems protected.

Answer (score 2):

NIST and MITRE are always good places to check for vulnerabilities. They both have pretty robust search functionalities:

- [NIST search for "microsoft windows"](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?form_type=Basic&results_type=overview&query=microsoft+windows&search_type=all)
- [MITRE search for "microsoft windows"](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=microsoft+windows)

Take a look. These might give some of the information you're looking for. If not, is there a specific feature or product within Windows that you're wondering about?